# Mongo java maching two or more values in mongo array

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to mongodb.I am trying to match username and password in collection array. My sample doc is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51f20148a85e39af87510305"),
    "group_name" : "sai",
    "users" : [
            {
                "full_name" : "sumit",
                "user_name" : "sumitdesh",
                "password" : "mggg",
                "status" : "Active"
            },
            {
                "full_name" : "ad",
                "user_name" : "asd",
                "password" : "asdf",
                "status" : "Active"
            },
}
```

I am trying to match user name and password enter by user in above array.If user name and password match with our data,user will get login.  My java code is

```
BasicDBObject u = new BasicDBObject("users.user_name", uname);
 BasicDBObject p = new BasicDBObject("users.password", password);
 f=con.coll.find(u,p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your document structure might get in the way here. How do you distinguish the user logging in? If you get a match, it will return the whole document, with all users.

Anyhow, to query with multiple comparisons:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
List<BasicDBObject> parts = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
parts.add(new BasicDBObject("users.user_name", uname));
parts.add(new BasicDBObject("users.password", password));
query.put("$and", parts);

DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/) query operator.

Something like this should work:

```
BasicDBObject elementQuery = new BasicDBObject("user_name", uname);
element.put("password", password);

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("users", 
                         new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", elementQuery);

f=con.coll.find(query);
```

Rob.

P.S. On a side note - having all of the users in a single document is probably not optimal.  Have you considered having a separate document for each user with the user name and password?

An example of a schema that might perform better is to divide the groups and users into two collections.  Each user will have a document like:

```
{
    "_id" : "sumitdesh",
    "full_name" : "sumit",
    "password" : "mggg",
    "status" : "Active"
    "groups" : [ "sai", "admin" ],
}
```

You will probably want to index the 'groups' if you query for all of the members of a group often.

The groups document will then look like:

```
{
    "_id" : "sai",
    "permissions" : [ "read", "write_secrets" ]
}
```

Index permissions.

A check for read permission for the sumitdesh user is then:

```
db.groups.findOne( 
    {
         _id : { "$in" : [ "sai", "admin" ] } , 
         "permissions" : "read" 
    } 
);
```

Note that the array for the '$in' same as the array of groups from 'sumitdesh' user document.

P.P.S. ...and when you say password you mean a hash (SHA-2?) of the salted password? Right?

Comment: What should be schema for this problem? I want users under group so that I can change group privileges.